# Using React-Recaptcha library without NPM

Tags: reactjs, captcha, react-proptypes

I'm brand new to React and trying to figure out how to use Ract-Recaptcha library (https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha) **without NPM.**

here is the source code for the Recaptcha wrapper : [index.js](https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha/blob/master/src/index.js)

Looks like the library imports   `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

and in my env NPM is disabled, so I'm wrecking my head ( with very limited React knowledge) trying to understand how to do without PropTypes.

Very much appreciate any help !!

Comment: why cant you use npm?

Comment: Management is paranoid and InfoSec rules the day. I think the fact that we even touch keyboards makes them jittery. I suppose in some beautiful future we're host our own repo , but for now I'm kinda screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the package into a `lib` directory or `private_modules` and import it manually and let Webpack (or whatever module bundler you use) resolve the dependency like code you've written.

In your package.json you can do something like:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "dependencies": {
    "myLocalModule": "file:./lib/myLocalModule/dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

Remember, this is our virtual world. There is always a way or at worst a hack! Cheers

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Comment: Josh, thanks for the response, but my env doesn't have direct access to the internet. I can download a tarball , but getting the whole dependency tree by hand would be too much of a chore. The question was more along the lines ot hacking the source code to remove PropTypes so I don' t have to get the dependent packages.

Comment: @JavaHead PropTypes only runs in development, the production build of that package should have PropTypes stripped out. If not, something is wrong with the production build where dead code removal via tree-shaking is not occurring (since PropTypes does not run in production builds). If that is the case, they would surely like to know that and would open an issue in that repository. Could also clone and build their project to a single production dist file yourself using webpack if that is not already done. Would be a single file to import.

Comment: Looks like react-racaptcha uses webpack and builds a distribution that is not under version control. Just clone repo, build project, and import file output to the dist folder.